# workflowState.Security.GetAccessRules() returns a Security Role that shouldn't exist

Tags: security, workflow

I have code that gets the AccessRules for a workflow state. My local dev environment has a role called "sitecore\ABC Admin" this role only exists on my local environment. We have our workflow items in a TDS project and deployed out to the other environments.

In QA when calling GetAccessRules an AccessRule of type AccountType.Role with an Account.Name of "sitecore\ABC Admin" is getting returned - causing us to have to add code that checks to see if the role exists first before continuing.

So the question is - where do I find what AccessRules exist in Content Editor for a user so I can to try and remove this phantom Role?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Security** is stored on the content items themselves so it's likely that when you deployed the workflow items through TDS to your QA environment, those items contain, in plain text, the names of the Security Roles that you configured on them in your **DEV** environment, even though the actual **Security Roles** haven't been created in your **QA** **Core** database.

To see this, you can go to the workflow items in question, turn on **Standard Fields** and expand the **Security** section of fields.  There, you should see the name of the **Security Roles** in question.

Comment: Great answer! To add on, if you are in the Access Viewer (not the Content Editor, so this isn't a valid answer on its own) you can also see the roles that have securities applied for an item. You can do the same in the Security Editor, but you must be on the actual item on which the securities were set for the "phantom role", so the Security Editor probably isn't super useful in this case. The `Security` field or the Access Viewer are your best bets, in this case.